# Problem transfering music not purchased on itunes to my iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I found some similar questions on here, but they are all from a few years ago and the answers don't seem to apply to the current version of itunes, so I thought I'd start a new question.

I downloaded a couple songs using an online youtube to mp3 converter. They show up in the itunes library on my computer, and I can play them on my computer. However, when I try to transfer them to my phone, itunes informs me it is "preparing to update" and "preparing to copy items", but then stops the process there.

Is there any way of transfering them?

**Additional information:**

- All the songs I purchased through the itunes store transfer over without any problems
- I have an old Toshiba with Windows 7 and an iphone 5s
- The non-purchased songs are MPEG audio files

I would very much appreciate any help, this has been frustrating me to no end!